# Pass command arguments as a variable

Tags: bash, scripts

I have made a bash script to back up my AWS Ligthsail server with restic.
Everything works finally, but there is one thing I couldn't find an answer.

Just the part where the problem is:

```
//Settings
forget_policy=(--keep-within-daily 7d --keep-within-weekly 1m --keep-within-monthly 1y --keep-within-yearly 2y)

//(… other code)

forget_old () {
    # Forget and prune
    restic -r $RESTIC_REPOSITORY forget "${forget_policy}" --prune | log

    # Check if exit status is ok
    status=$?
    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        log "Forget failed ${status}"
        exit 1
    fi
}

//(… other code)

forget_old
```

Output

```
>> invalid argument "--prune" for "--keep-within-daily" flag: no number found
```

I can't pass the $forget_policy variable to the forget command. When I wrap the varibale in "" I get

```
>> unknown flag: --keep-within-daily 7d --keep-within-weekly 1m --keep-within-monthly 1y --keep-within-yearly 2y
```

When I copy the variable content directly to the command, it works. So I must be doing something wrong with passing the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand *each* of the elements of your argument array as a separate word you need `"${forget_policy[@]}"`

`"${forget_policy}"` is equivalent to `"${forget_policy[0]}"` so only expands to the first argument - which is why you end up with `--keep-within-daily --prune`

See the `Arrays` subsection under `PARAMETERS` in the bash manual page.

Comment: Thanks. I do (sadly) not enough bash scripting. Didn't notice I turned it to an array, adding the (). Before, I had just "forget_policy="--keep-within-daily 7d --…". That's just a string and didn't work. Had googeled and found the "array version"

Comment: @Rever_2019 in that case it was a happy accident - using an array is exactly the right way to handle this kind of argument list ;)